# A is positive definite, B is positive semidefinite and all the diagonal element is positive, prove that Schur product their is positive definite

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product

> $A$ is positive definite, $B$ is positive semidefinite and all the diagonal element is positive, prove that $A\circ B$ is positive definite

It is easy to prove it with Oppenheim Inequality:

> Apparently $A\circ B$ is positive semi-definite.
>
> Since $\det(A\circ B)\geq \det A\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n b_{ii} >0 $ (Oppenheim), $A\circ B$ is positive definite(all its eigenvalue is positive).

However, can it be proved without the inequality?

I tried to use mathematical induction:

> For $n=1$, apparently $A\circ B > 0$.
>
> If  $\forall k<n, k>0, \forall A_k, B_k\in M_k$, $A_k$ is positive definite, $B_k$ is positive semi-defenite and all its eigenvalue is positive $\Rightarrow$ $A\circ B$ is positive definite.
>
> Then we only have to prove that $\det A\circ B >0$.  Let $A_{ij}$ represent A without $i$th row and $j$th coloumn, we have:
>
> $\det A\circ B = \sum_{j=1}^na_{1j}\cdot b_{1j}\cdot\det A_{1j}\circ B_{1j} $

But I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proof I prefer: if $A$ has eigendecomposition $A = U\Lambda U^*$ (where $\Lambda$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $\lambda_j$ and $U$ is unitary with columns $u_i$), then we have
$$
A = U\Lambda U^* = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j u_ju_j^*
$$
Now, note that 
$$
(u_ju_j^*) \circ B = \operatorname{diag}(u_j)B\operatorname{diag}(u_j)^*
$$
Where $\operatorname{diag}(u_j)$ denotes the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the entries of the vector $u_j$.  Thus, we see that $(u_ju_j^*) \circ B$ is positive semidefinite.  With that, we note that
$$
A \circ B = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j u_ju_j^* \right) \circ B = 
\sum_{j=1}^n(u_ju_j^*) \circ (\lambda_j B)
$$
which means that $A \circ B$ is a sum of positive semidefinite, and is therefore itself positive semidefinite.